# YouTube API V3 para Pegar Lista de Videos das Inscrições

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, api-youtube

Estou criando uma página onde preciso pegar todos os vídeos que localiza na página "http://www.youtube.com/feed/subscriptions" do usuário. Procurei em todas a paginas das api's v3 do Google Developer Youtube mais não encontrei algo que retorne apenas os vídeos dos canais que estou seguindo.

Comment: Está usando apenas HTML e Javascript?

Comment: Por enquanto sim, mais se precisar usarei PHP para puxar os dados.